# How many tokens should I create for different types of integer?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I'm trying to implement a lexical analyzer for a language that has these types of ints:

int32
int64
uint32
uint64
sint32
sint64
fixed32 
fixed64 
sfixed32
sfixed64

my question is: should I create a different token for each one of them? And should I create a REGEX for each one as well? This is my code so far:

```
%{
enum Tokens{
L_INT = 1,
L_DOUBLE,
L_FLOAT,
L_BOOL,
L_STRING,
L_BYTE,
RW_REQUIRED,
RW_OPTIONAL,
RW_REPEATED,
RW_MESSAGE,
RW_IMPORT,
RW_PUBLIC,
RW_ENUM,
RW_SERVICE,
RW_CHANNEL,
RW_CONTROLLER,
A_RPAR,
A_LPAR,
C_RPAR,
C_LPAR
};
%}
%option nodefault noyywrap
%%
"(" { return A_RPAR; }
")" { return A_LPAR; }
"{" { return C_RPAR; }
"}" { return C_LPAR; }
"required" { return RW_REQUIRED; }
"optional" { return RW_OPTIONAL; }
"repeated" { return RW_REPEATED; }
"message" { return RW_MESSAGE; }
"import" { return RW_IMPORT; }
"public" { return RW_PUBLIC; }
"enum" { return RW_ENUM; }
"service" { return RW_SERVICE; }
"channel" { return RW_CHANNEL; }
"controller" { return RW_CONTROLLER; }
"true" { return L_BOOL; }
"false" { return L_BOOL; }
[\r\n ] {}
([0-1]) { printf("[%s]", yytext); return L_BYTE; }
(0|[1-9][0-9]*) { printf("[%s]", yytext); return L_INT; }
(0|[1-9][0-9]*)?\.[0-9]+ { printf("[%s]", yytext); return L_DOUBLE; }
(0|[1-9][0-9]*)?\.[0-9]+[fF] { printf("[%s]", yytext); return L_FLOAT; }
([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*) { printf("[%s]", yytext); return L_STRING; }
. { printf("caractere invalido [%s] \n", yytext); return 0;}
%%
extern FILE *yyin;
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
int token = -1;
if (argc <2){
printf("Exemplo: %s [arquivo_entradas]",argv[0]);
return 1;
}
yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
while(token = yylex()) {
printf("Token = %d\n", token);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the keywords for the integer types, or the integers themselves?

Comment: The integer themselves. My main doubt is: How/when will I tell the types of ints apart?

Comment: Yes, that was my question, too. Integers are integers (unless this is C-like and you have suffixes). I think EJP assumes you mean the keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Keep them all different in the lexical analyser and the parser. If the question about creating a regex means doing what you're already doing for the other keywords, the answer is also yes.

When keyword sets get very large, as for example in Cobol-85 and successors, where there are well oer 400, you may consider just having one rule for all identifiers and looking up a Hashtable of keywords when you get an identifier, instead of a rule per keyword: a space-time trade off, as otherwise the flex tables get huge. But I doubt you have this problem.

**EDIT** If you're just talking about integer *literals,* you don't have any choice. The lexical analyser doesn't have the information required to sort them into different types. You should just return INTEGER from your lexical rule. Unless the numbers have prefixes or suffixes (like C's `L`), which lets you determine it. But I consider that poor language design, whoever did it, maybe the BCPL or B guys, or DR. There was never any real necessity for it.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. I'm using a token called L_INT to match with a given number. But how can I say if that given int is a int32, int 36, etc? Is it handled on the lexical analyzer level?

Comment: Integer *literals* are *another* token type. Matching them to the required target type is semantic analysis. Nothign to do with the lexical analyser.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are going to insist that integers be written in a C-like fashion with some kind of type suffix -- as you seem to do for floating point numbers --, there is absolutely no way that a lexical analyser can really tell whether a given positive integer is an instance of a signed type or not, for example. So my thinking is that it shouldn't even try.

You could, of course, do a partial analysis, based on the magnitude of the integer and whether or not it is signed, but in the end the integer can (presumably) be used as a value of any type which it fits into, so `12` could be any of the 10 types you list. (It possibly could also work as a floating point number.) So a partial analysis really won't tell you anything necessary for the *syntax* of your language, and that makes it wasted effort in a lexical analyser.

That leaves open the question of how you *represent* the semantic value of the integer, since the union of the possible values of all 10 of those types will not fit into 64 bits. (The range runs from -2<sup>63</sup> to 2<sup>64</sup>-1.) If your language will allow arithmetic expressions, you can avoid the problem by considering `-` to always be an operator, and never part of a literal integer. Then the possible legal values for integers fit into the range of an unsigned 64-bit integer (`uint64_t` in C), which is a plausible semantic value type.

Since your semantic values also include floating point numbers, you will need to use a discriminated union of some kind; you could use that mechanism to also record whether or not the integer was written with a sign (which is not the same thing as being a signed value), but that seems clunky to me. In any event, it *probably* has nothing to do with syntax, unless your syntax has some corner case where only an integer constant is allowed (no expressions) but the constant can be negative. I'd avoid such syntactic rules, too.

I notice that your code attempts to specifically categorize 0 and 1 as "byte" (although it seems like "bit" would be more accurate), but I'd recommend not doing that either. You'll still need a semantic value in order to distinguish the 0 from the 1, and either of those constants could just as well be used in a non-boolean (syntactic) context, so you're not really buying yourself anything by generating a different lexical token.

When you do finally do the semantic analysis, you will need to range-check the semantic values against the derived datatype. If you wanted to, you could get the lexical analyser to compute the range category of each integer, storing it in another member of the semantic type structure. But that's probably not worth the trouble.